# MVC model shows null for date field. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building ASP.NET MVC web application for making appointment bookings. When I am retrieving bookings from database, the date column shows as `Null` in the front end despite database having valid date values.

I have a model called `Booking` with below property/field. Both `Date` & `_Date` fields show up as `Null` when I retrieve the field called `Date` from the database. I can confirm that Setter methods work fine and save the Local date in UTC time in the database.

```
[Display(Name = "Date", ResourceType = typeof(Fields))]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
[NotMapped]
public DateTime? Date
{
    get { return _Date; }
    set
    {
        _LocalDateTime = value;
        if (_Date is null)
        { 
            _Date = DateUtilities.FromTimeZone(_LocalDateTime + LocalTime);   
        }
    }
}

[Column("Date",TypeName = "Date")]
public DateTime? _Date { get; set; }

public DateTime? _LocalDateTime;
```

I have below controller that fetches the booking from database.

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? id = null)
{
    var booking = new Booking();
    if (id == null) return View(booking);
    booking = Uow.Bookings.Get(u => u.Id == id);
    if (booking == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(booking);
}
```

I have traced the SQL query that gets sent via Uow.Bookings.Get and ran that query in database and got proper date values such as

> Date = 2019-05-17

here is my view

```
<div class="mb-lg">
    @Model.Date.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd MMM yyyy") - 
    @Utilities.TimeSpanToHours(Model.StartTime, true)
</div>
```

I expect that `Date`/`_Date` property/field will return valid value of `2019-05-17` from the database.

Comment: If you debug, does the setter for `Date` run when you execute the query? Second question, why do you even have two date fields?

Comment: what is `FromTimeZone` method supposed to do and from where is `LocalTime` variable within it supposed to get value from?

Comment: Setter doesn't run when the query is executed.

Comment: LocaDateTime is part of the setter method and get's value from there. Not sure If I wrote that code correctly.    FromTimeZone converts LocalTime to UTC time. Code below :                 
    public static DateTime? FromTimeZone(DateTime? dateTime)
        {
            if (dateTime == null) return null;
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime.Value, _nzdZone);
        }

Comment: Since your setter isn't getting run, your `FromTimeZone` logic isn't getting called. Have you checked if after executing the query there is any data in the `Date` property? You'll probably need to place a breakpoint before returning the view so as to check if you have data.